# Unable to redirect Salesforce links to Salesforce App

Tags: ios, applications, safari, url

I'm unable to open the Salesforce links in Salesforce App. The links are directly opening in Safari, but they need to open in the Salesforce App rather than the browser.

Is there some settings involved so that iOS is able to recognise the App by clicking on a link? How do I get this to work?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) On your iOS device, can you go to Settings app → Safari and check if the switch shown against Safari Suggestions is turned on?

Answer (score 2):

To open Salesforce links within Salesforce app, you should encode them following the correct scheme.

A request to Salesforce for Android and iOS URL scheme follows this format:

```
<scheme_name>://sObject/<id>/<action>
```

Let’s break down each parameter of the URL scheme format:

- scheme_name: Supported Salesforce for Android and iOS scheme names.
- sObject: Indicates a single instance of a Salesforce object.
- id: The unique single instance of a Salesforce object. id lengths of 15 and
- 18 characters are supported.
- action: Supported URL scheme operations

For example, to open Salesforce for Android and iOS and navigate to a specific record, the URL scheme will look similar to:

```
salesforce1://sObject/001D000000Jwj9v/view
```

---

**Scheme Names**

Salesforce supports the following scheme_name parameters for URL schemes:

- salesforce1://

---

**Actions**

These are the available action parameters for URL schemes.

- view: Navigates the user to the Salesforce app to view a record in detail.
- edit: Navigates the user to the edit detail page of a record.
- home: Navigates the user to the home page of an object.
- download: Download any version of a file.
- follow: Follow users to see their posts, comments, and likes in your feed.

Note: The user must have proper permissions to view, edit, download, etc within Salesforce directly, so if it's not opening the correct section of the Salesforce app - first validate they have access to the actions you're attempting to bring them to - otherwise they usually end up on the home screen.

Resource Links: 
https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce1_url_schemes.pdf 
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000l3wlQAA